# leaflet: toggle labels depending which layer is active

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I have a leaflet map with three layers that load from separate geoJSON files. 
I have three additional files with latlong coordinates and labels for each one.

I am using basemap control.layers to switch between my three layers, and I would like to have an overlay layer checkbox that will enable the labels layer, depending on which basemap layer is active.

```
var basemaps= {
"layer1": layer1,
"layer2": layer 2,
"layer3": layer 3
};
```

I am using layerGroups to keep my labels together.
I tried using the ActiveLayer plugin to help me pick which baselayer is currently active, but something always seems to be out of order.

I am new to javascript and learning as I go.

The rest of my control code:

```
var picker = L.control.activeLayers(basemaps, showlabels {collapsed:false}).addTo(map);

if (picker.getActiveBaseLayer() == "layer1")
    {activelabel = label1};
if (picker.getActiveBaseLayer() == "layer2")
    {activelabel = label2};
if (picker.getActiveBaseLayer() == "layer2")
    {activelabel = label3};

var showlabels = {
"labels": activelabel
};
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I want to have radio buttons for my layers and one checkbox for my labels that changes labels depending which radio button is checked.

EDIT

I found this code, the baselayerchange

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function(a) {
if (picker.getActiveBaseLayer().name == "layer1")
{activelabel = label1};
if (picker.getActiveBaseLayer().name == "layer2")
{activelabel = label2};
if (picker.getActiveBaseLayer().name == "layer3")
{activelabel = labels3};
});
```

It seems to do something, when I do a console.log it tells me the active layer, but for some reason it isnt updating which labels are showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several base layers, with separate overlays (containing labels in your case) associated with each base layer. You want the overlays to be toggable, but only the one associated with the current base layer should be shown.

You do not necessarily need the [ActiveLayers](https://github.com/vogdb/Leaflet.ActiveLayers) plugin to achieve this.

As you figured out, you need to setup an event listener to "manually" assign the appropriate labels overlay. The [`"baselayerchange"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-baselayerchange) event is indeed appropriate, but just assigning the new labels to your `activelabel` variable is not enough, because the Layers Control used the value it had when you instantiated it.

Instead, you should make your `activelabel` a [Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layergroup), and on `"baselayerchange"`, first [`clearLayers`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layergroup-clearlayers) then re-add the appropriate labels layer into it.

```js
var activelabel = L.layerGroup();
var showlabels = {
  "labels": activelabel
};

map.on('baselayerchange', function (event) {
  activelabel.clearLayers();

  switch (event.layer) {
    case layer1:
      label1.addTo(activelabel);
      break;
    case layer2:
      layer2.addTo(activelabel);
      break;
    case layer3:
      layer3.addTo(activelabel);
      break;
  }
});
```

Live demo: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/zosa/1/edit?html,output

Another possible solution would be to use the [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) plugin, which will enable you to associate each labels overlay with its corresponding base layer, but have the plugin add the overlay into a toggable Layer Group.

```js
// Layer Group container for labels overlays.
var labelsGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);


// Base layer 1: use a container Layer Group for the Tile Layer
// and a SubGroup that will receive the labels,
// to be sent into labelsGroup when the base layer is selected.
var group1 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var subgroup1 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(labelsGroup).addTo(group1);

base1.addTo(group1);
labels1.addTo(subgroup1);


// Base layer 2.
var group2 = L.layerGroup();
var subgroup2 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(labelsGroup).addTo(group2);

base2.addTo(group2);
labels2.addTo(subgroup2);


L.control.layers({
  // Base layers.
  'Base 1': group1,
  'Base 2': group2
}, {
  // Overlays. This will switch on/off the labels.
  'Labels': labelsGroup
}).addTo(map);
```

Live demo: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/pasu/1/edit?html,output

While this solution requires 2 extra Layer Groups per Base Layer, it avoids having to set up the event listener yourself, which can be a little bit cumbersome if you have plenty base layers.

> Disclaimer: I am the author of Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup plugin.

Comment: Thats fantastic! Thank you so much!